# How do I add pem file to Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have Dialogflow Fulfillment setup on my own private server but can't get it working with https. I have created a certificate using letsencrypt and I get the correct  response using Postman with SSL certificate verification enabled. However I get a response of "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE." from Dialogflow

Can someone please walk me through the steps of adding the certificate pem file to Dialogflow (if thats what I need to do)

Comment: Would you mind posting the following: Full stack trace error, Script of fulfillment and steps to reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the certificates were working fine and it was another issue (v1 to v2 migration changes) not related to https that was causing the error.

It would be great if Dialogflow gave more descriptive error messages.

Thanks to anyone who read this.

Answer (score 0):

What are the logs? To see if we can see the issue. Also, check the dependencies. Also, if your certificate is not formated correctly, you can do the following to get the right cert, and the right key as well...

One of the best things to do here is to use the following [tool](https://www.digicert.com/util/)

To make sure you can see your certificate in your local machine, and then, you can hover over your certificate, and you can click on the export certificate where you can choose the .pem file with the key as an individual file.

If you don't see your certificate here, you will have to import the cert through the utility tool, and if you get the following error message "Private key does not match with current certificate" You will have to create a new CSR, and you will have to reissue your certificate to be able to import it into the utility tool. Then, you should be able to export the same certificate as a .pem file.